# Xcode Localization Not Working?

Tags: objective-c, macos, localization, xcode4.5, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to add a new localization for my app for Mac OS X (Mountain Lion). 
I added the appropriate localizations to the project info panel and made all the `.xib` files localized. I also added and translated the .strings file and replaced the .xib files with the translated strings file. 
Then everything seemed to be working, and the interface builder showed appropriate translations for each localization `xib` file. However, when I actually run the app, it is shown in English, although the default language for my system is not English. 
I also have a `Localizable.strings` file for some of the labels, and for those that I used `NSLocalizedString` works fine.
I'm not sure what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Perform build clean ( Command-Option-Shift-K)
2. Remove the app from simulator/device
3. Launch the app

Comment: Thank you! It now works. Didn't think about the clean build :(

Comment: You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Check that you marked Target Membership of your Target. I had the same problem, because I had add my string manually.

Look at the image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't work because the UILabel text was set as "Attributed" instead of "Plain" in the Attributes Inspector.
Localization with a .strings file doesn't seem to work on Attributed strings.
I even had a storyboard with mixed Plain and Attributed string labels, and the localization only worked on the Plain ones.

Also, check that there are no syntax errors in your Localizable.strings (end each line with ";")