# Making localization work

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, internationalization

I have an app that needs to be localized.

After fiddling with the settings for a while, I managed to get the project to the state where it builds a `nl.lproj` (amongst others) directory in the `Resources` directory of the app bundle, which contains a `MainMenu.strings` file that contains all my translations; they seem correct at first glance.

The XIB file is marked as translatable, and seems to be part of the right target:

[image: xib localization settings]

However, if I run the app in a dutch environment, the localized strings are not shown in the UI. I added

```
NSLocale *loc = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
NSString *lang = [loc languageCode];
NSLog(@"Current language: %@",lang);
```

to verify that the Dutch language is active, and it is.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037753/xcode-localization-not-working) suggests that doing a clean followed by a rebuild of the app should fix such issues. I've tried that, but it did not resolve the issue.

How can I figure out why my app isn't being translated? What else could go wrong? Are there any diagnostics I could be checking?

The application in question is open source, and can be found at https://github.com/Fedict/eid-mw. Select the "eID Viewer" target, and build that, to see what's happening.

Comment: Show us how you set a localized string to an NSTextField object or whatever.

Comment: @ElTomato updated the question to show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that localisation is supported with OSX 10.8 and above. My app had selected 10.7 as deployment target (we do need to support a few older versions of OSX). Switching the deployment target to 10.8 makes the translations appear.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I have pointed you to the right direction. All the best for your app localization.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things with the localization. One is localization the UI. This is done by checking those boxes and then editing the string files in the dialog underneath the xib file.
[image: Window for localization of UI]
[image: Window with the UI localization strings]

The second is the localization of the Userfacing strings in code. This is done by the Macro `NSLocalizedString(@"*key*", *comment*);` where key is the key and comment is a provided comment for localization purpose.
[image]

These strings are the to edit in the File Localizable.strings.

Here a link with a Beginner [Tutorial](https://www.oneskyapp.com/academy/learn-ios-localization/). And the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html)

To activate the debug function in Xcode for localized strings: pass in `-NSShowNonLocalizedStrings YES` as launch argument in Xcode. You find it under Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme -Arguments
[image]
Hope this helps

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that an app can hung up before it starts up.

Comment: Thanks for the input. You're right the cursor was misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the documentation and the explanation of how it's *supposed* to work. I had already found all that though. My question is not about "how is this done"; it is about "if you do what the docs say and it doesn't work, how do you debug it". I'm probably missing something obvious here, but my app, which *should* be translated, is not. I'm not using `NSLocalizedString()` since it's not needed for my app, but the xib file localization is. I checked all the right boxes (I think), but it still doesn't work. I'm at a loss for how to fix it...

Comment: My guess is, you missed to fill out the .strings file from the UI. The picture above shows you an demo UI, named Insector.xib. After checking the boxes as seen in picture 1 you will find underneath the xib file different files with the same name, but the .strings suffix. After editing that files like in the example it should work.

Comment: @voltae no, there are .strings files. Also, when I say "export localization", the generated XML file does contain the translations. I can reimport them and the .strings files get regenerated. However, the compiled application does not contain the translations.

Comment: and when I say "does not contain the translations", I mean they do not show up. If I open the app bundle, there are nl.lproj and de.lproj etc directories under `Resources/`, which do contain the .strings files as well; the translated strings are available there.

Comment: Are in that .strings files the syntax like /* Class = "SNButtonCell"; title = "fill"; ObjectID = "someID"; */ It happen when there is a syntax error in that .strings file the hole translation will not show up. Please provide a snippet of that .strings file.

Comment: @voltae -- I can do better than a snippet; the files are available at, e.g., https://github.com/Fedict/eid-mw/blob/master/plugins_tools/eid-viewer/OSX/eID%20Viewer/eID%20Viewer/nl.lproj/MainMenu.strings (also in french and german though).

Answer (score 0):

You need called .strings file with name "Localizable.strings".
And add language target ( in inspector ) and fill target language file.

Comment: I have already done all that. The "Localizable.strings" is empty, since I never use any NSLocalizedString (or what was it again) call, but the .lproj directories do contain MainMenu.strings files, and those have the required strings. However they do not show up in the localized .xib files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a check with pseudolocalozations?
Are you setting properly the language and region on your mac?
Are you also trying launching it specifically in Dutch from XCode:

To launch your app in a specific language and region

1. Click the target in the Run destination menu and choose Edit Scheme.
2. On the right, select Options.
3. Optionally, choose a language from the Application Language pop-up menu.
4. Optionally, choose a region from the Application Region pop-up menu.
5. Click the Close button.
6. Click Run to launch your app in the language and region you specified.

Comment: Interesting. When I try to run my app with the double-length pseudolocalization, that also doesn't work. Not sure why, but at least it's progress...

Comment: Since this got me on the right track towards figuring out what was wrong (even pseudolocales didn't work...), I'm going to assign the bounty to you. Thanks!